# Need to remove duplicate tuples based on length of the tuple in a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

Hi i have list as below:
for sample:

```
l = [('b','a','c'),('a','c','d','f'),('a','y','f'),('b','a'),('a','c'), ('b','g')]
```

Now i need to remove only ('b','a') tuple but not ('b','a','c') likewise ('a','c') need to remove, so basically I need to remove tuple if the length == 2 and it has to be duplicate tuple.

I need output as:

```
[('b','a','c'),('a','c','d','f'),('a','y','f'), ('b','g')]
```

Here `('b','g')` shouldn't be removed because it is not matched with any other tuple.

Comment: `(b,a)` also has no duplicate ?

Comment: actually based on strings we need to take b, a combination is in ('b','a','c')

Comment: do you always want to retain the longest? or the first in your list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary keyed by the first 2 elements of a tuple to keep track of how many "duplicates" there are for a given tuple. Then you can ignore 2 element tuples that aren't unique in the final result:

```
l = [('32822', '32891'), ('32822', '32891', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-02', '10.88.163.113'), ('32891', '32781'), ('32781', '32822'), ('32781', '32822', 'EKRGMD92-vMME-01', '10.88.158.81', 'KSCYMOEC-MME-03', '10.148.9.19'), ('32781', '33033', 'KSCYMOEC-MME-03', '10.148.9.19'), ('32781', '33033'), ('32891', '33033'), ('32822', '33033')]

groups = {}
for t in l:
    k = t[:2]
    groups.setdefault(k, []).append(t)

result = [t for t in l if len(t) > 2 or len(groups[t]) == 1]

print(result)
# [('32822', '32891', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-02', '10.88.163.113'), ('32891', '32781'), ('32781', '32822', 'EKRGMD92-vMME-01', '10.88.158.81', 'KSCYMOEC-MME-03', '10.148.9.19'), ('32781', '33033', 'KSCYMOEC-MME-03', '10.148.9.19'), ('32891', '33033'), ('32822', '33033')]
```

Comment: Sorry it is not working for actual my input may be because of using set, i don't want to use set bcz it'll change the order of tuples

Comment: l = [('32822', '32891'), ('32822', '32891', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-02', '10.88.163.113'), ('32891', '32781'), ('32781', '32822'), ('32781', '32822', 'EKRGMD92-vMME-01', '10.88.158.81', 'KSCYMOEC-MME-03', '10.148.9.19'), ('32781', '33033', 'KSCYMOEC-MME-03', '10.148.9.19'), ('32781', '33033'), ('32891', '33033'), ('32822', '33033')]

Comment: here between ('32822', '32891'), ('32822', '32891', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-02', '10.88.163.113') i just want ('32822', '32891', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-02', '10.88.163.113') not the other

Comment: @smilydips I didn't know that a 2 element tuple could come before the one you wanted. I think the updated answer is more like what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only one the longest tuple and drop the shorter ones with items that are subsets of the items in the list:

```
l = [('b','a','c'),('a','c','d','f'),('a','y','f'),('b','a'),('a','c'), ('b','g')]
l = sorted(l, key = lambda x: len(x))

for idx,tup in enumerate(l):
    if any(all(i in t for i in tup) for t in l[idx+1:]):
        pass #do nothing
    else:
        print(tup) #print unique longest tuple
```

`sort` the lines so you will always compare the shorter lines first, and by using enumerate and setting the offset you are always comparing to the longer tuples ahead. `all` compares each subset of the tuple to the ones ahead and `any` returns `True` if all of the subsets are in a longer tuple, irrespective of the length.

Comment: Sorry i don't want sorting but anyways thanks for your response.